# Inconsistent namespacing for maps?

Tags: erlang

I think namespacing of maps (at least in R19) is pretty weird. Consider the example:

```
14> M = #{a => 2, b => 3, c => 4}.
#{a => 2,b => 3,c => 4}
15> M.
#{a => 2,b => 3,c => 4}
16> map_size(M).                                    
3
17> maps:map_size(M).
** exception error: undefined function maps:map_size/1
18> to_list(M).      
** exception error: undefined shell command to_list/1
19> maps:to_list(M).
[{a,2},{b,3},{c,4}]
```

So, `map_size` is available in default namespace but not in `maps:`. However, `to_list/1` exhibits opposite behavior. I haven't tried other functions, but even these results are surprising.

Am I missing some important undercurrent here or is this just an example of carelessness in language design?

Comment: There is `maps:size` because it doesn't make sense to call a function `map_` in `maps` module. I believe the `map_size` is also in the default namespace because it's allowed in guards, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Dogbert Nice explanation! `maps:size` was new to me, and the whole thing kinda makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some logic to this.  The `map_size/1` function is also available as [`maps:size/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#size-1), where both names contain the information you need: it takes a map, and returns the size.  On the other hand, the name `to_list` doesn't say what you're converting from.  There are several `to_list` functions in the default namespace already:

- `atom_to_list`
- `binary_to_list`
- `float_to_list`
- `integer_to_list`
- `pid_to_list`
- `tuple_to_list`

So the inconsistency here is that while "size" is available as `map_size/1` and `maps:size/1`, the function `map_to_list` is missing.  As Dogbert notes in the comments, this is presumably because `map_size` is available in guard tests, and thus deserves a special place.  (I seem to remember that there are functions in other modules that are available in guard tests, but my memory might be deceiving me.)